# syntax error while trying to install a module using pip

Tags: python, syntax-error

i tried to re install multiple times and to add pip to my path and everything i dont know what to do now (im a beginner)

```
       C:\Users\tamin>pip install pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\tamin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tamin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\pip.py", line 1
    C:> py -m ensurepip --upgrade
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```